# Understanding TCP Slow Start

Tags: tcp

I was trying to get my head around tcp congestion control and came across what is called the slow start phase, where tcp starts by sending just 1 MSS and then keep on adding 1 MSS to the congestion window on receipt of an ack. This much is clear. But after this, almost all books/articles that i refers goes ahead a say that this results in doubling the cwnd every RTT showing a image something like below where i got confused.

[image: RTT]

The first segment is clear, tcp sends it and receives the ack after a RTT and then doubles the cwnd which now is 2. Now it transmits two segments, the ack for the fist one comes after RTT making the cwnd 3. But the ack for the second segment comes after this making cwnd 4(ie doubling it). So i am not able to understand how the cwnd doubles every RTT, since as per my understanding, in this example, cwnd doubled on the first RTT and got incremented by one on the second RTT and again doubled on some other time(RTT+tx time of the first segment i believe). Is this understanding correct. Please explain.

Comment: When cwnd is (say) 2, both ACKS (or one for both segments) arrive in quick succession (and not after 2 * RTT) if no congestion is present. In other words, before the next group of segments is sent. That´s why the algorithm effectively doubles the cws.

Answer (score 0):

After the two segments' acks had been received by the sender, the CWND was increased by 2, not 1.  Note that the second ack in round 2 arrived right after the first ack in round 2, that's why they were considered in the same round and costed 1 RTT.

Answer (score 0):

I can not agree with you more. I think there is not exist a double mechanism and they get the wrong meaning for the Slow Start.

When the server receives the ACK, the cwnd will increase the value of 1 MSS. So if you send n requests and receive all the ACK, cwnd will become (n + n) MSS.

In the process of Slow Start, the requests can be done in 1 RTT, because it is not easy to happend traffic jam in the Internet. So it looks like it become double per RTT. But, the real mechanism is to add, not multiply.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained perfectly in the video:

https://youtube.com/watch?v=Ycy4VWr3-24

So MSS is Maximum Segment Size that how many segments are sent at a particular time and the incremental approach is such that congestion window is incremented by 1 MSS everytime.